# My JavaScript RC4 code ruins my original text

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, rc4-cipher

I've tried everything from changing a few variables, to the integers and also trying to look for answers online. I know that **RC4** is not that secure, but I only need it for a simple project.

The issue is whenever I try to encrypt a huge character count of text and when I decrypt it, it returns gibberish as in the decrypted text is not the same as the original text as some of it is missing.

My Code:

```js
var RC4key = "Arc"; //My secret key.

var contentValue = "The-Message"; //My plaintext message that I wish to encrypt.

function rc4Encrypt(key, pt) {
  s = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    s[i] = i;
  }
  var j = 0;
  var x;
  for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    j = (j + s[i] + key.charCodeAt(i % key.length)) % 255;
    x = s[i];
    s[i] = s[j];
    s[j] = x;
  }
  i = 0;
  j = 0;
  var ct = '';
  for (var y = 0; y < pt.length; y++) {
    i = (i + 1) % 255;
    j = (j + s[i]) % 255;
    x = s[i];
    s[i] = s[j];
    s[j] = x;
    ct += String.fromCharCode(pt.charCodeAt(y) ^ s[(s[i] + s[j]) % 255]);
  }
  return ct;
}

/*rc4Decrypt is used to decrypt the encrypted text to the original as long as the key is correct.*/
function rc4Decrypt(key, ct) {
  return rc4Encrypt(key, ct);
}

/*I am trying to encrypt it and placing the value in "valueEncrypted" variable.*/
var valueEncrypted = rc4Encrypt(RC4key, contentValue);

/*I am outputting the value to the console.*/
console.log(valueEncrypted);
```

- **Please don't apply base64 or any other sort of encoding schemes as it is not required.**
- **Yes, I know I can use CryptoJS or other libraries, but I prefer to use it in vanilla (pure) JavaScript as it is required for my project to not use any dependencies to achieve this.**

Thank you to everyone who has read my post and given it a thought. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Your code is printing the encrypted value, which should be gibberish. I get the correct result when I decrypt it with `console.log(rc4Decrypt(RC4key, valueEncrypted));`

Comment: @JamesKPolk Hi, James, thanks for the suggestion. I did compare it to a few other implementations available on this website before asking this question, but it did not fix this issue. I am very confused as to why my Rivest cipher implementation is giving me errors or not returning the plain text input correctly.

Comment: Could you explain the problem more clearly? As I said above, it decrypts your example correctly.

Comment: `% 255` should be `% 256`

Comment: @Barmar Hi, thanks for your suggestion. Yes, I know that, but it gives errors when the text input is too large, for example more than 2 or 3 paragraphs. Any other solution to solve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Put an example of the problem in the question, not working code.

Comment: Because of that, it will fail whenever the input is longer than 255 characters.

Comment: Yes, I did try that too I originally had % 255 set at %256 and it still gave me errors. I tried both methods. Still no luck :(

Comment: There's pseudo-code in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4) article

Comment: @Barmar thank you, I will have a look at it.